# Интервалы между двумя датами с группировкой

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть таблица, в которой:

```
  event_name(Purchase, SessionStartm, SessionEnd)
, event_time
, user_id
, registration_time
```

В рамках одного пользователя последовательность событий во времени может выглядеть примерно так:

1. SessionStart
2. SessionEnd
3. SessionStart
4. Purchase
5. SessionEnd
6. SessionStart
7. SessionEnd
8. SessionStart
9. Purchase
10. SessionEnd

Задача: для пользователей, зарегистрировавшихся в игре за последние 100 дней, получить распределение по времени, проведённому в игре, до совершения первой покупки.

Ответ должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
┌─time─┬─users_count─┐
│ 1200 │          10 │
│ 1260 │          13 │
│ 1320 │          17 │
│ 1380 │          19 │
│ 1440 │           1 │
│ 1500 │           8 │
│ 1560 │          11 │
└──────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: `time` у вас в каких единицах?  Постгрес всё же или Май?

Comment: Если MySQL - какая ТОЧНО версия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PostgreSQL*.  Для *MySQL* придётся использовать
его функции работы с интервалами.  Не уверен, можно ли
проще, но как-то так:

```sql
WITH earliest_events AS (
  SELECT MIN(event_id) AS event_id
       , MIN(event_time) AS event_time
    FROM events
   GROUP BY event_name
       , user_id
)
, user_times AS (
  SELECT user_id
       , TRUNC(
           EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM purchase.event_time - start.event_time) / 60
         ) * 60 AS time
    FROM events AS start
         INNER JOIN earliest_events AS earliest_starts
            ON start.event_id = earliest_starts.event_id
          LEFT JOIN events AS purchase
         USING (user_id) 
         INNER JOIN earliest_events AS earliest_purchases
            ON purchase.event_id = earliest_purchases.event_id
   WHERE start.event_name = 'SessionStart'
     AND purchase.event_name = 'Purchase'
)
SELECT time
     , COUNT(user_id) AS users_count
  FROM user_times
 GROUP BY time
;
```

```
 time | users_count 
------+-------------
   60 |           2
  120 |           1
```

*DB-Fiddle*:
[https://
www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmoFYZm8hjDnNNrJkkttUF/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmoFYZm8hjDnNNrJkkttUF/0).

---

**Вторая версия**, без `event_id`.  Так как вы так и не
указали, что в таблице является первичным ключом, я взял сочетание
`user_id` и `event_time`.  Если и это не является
первичным ключом — сами.

```sql
WITH earliest_events AS (
  SELECT MIN(event_time) AS event_time
       , user_id
    FROM events
   GROUP BY event_name
       , user_id
)
, user_times AS (
  SELECT start.user_id
       , TRUNC(
           EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM purchase.event_time - start.event_time) / 60
         ) * 60 AS time
    FROM events AS start
         INNER JOIN earliest_events AS earliest_starts
            ON start.event_time = earliest_starts.event_time
           AND start.user_id = earliest_starts.user_id
          LEFT JOIN events AS purchase
            ON start.user_id = purchase.user_id
         INNER JOIN earliest_events AS earliest_purchases
            ON purchase.event_time = earliest_purchases.event_time
           AND purchase.user_id = earliest_purchases.user_id
   WHERE start.event_name = 'SessionStart'
     AND purchase.event_name = 'Purchase'
)
SELECT time
     , COUNT(user_id) AS users_count
  FROM user_times
 GROUP BY time
;
```

Comment: *Для MySQL придётся повозиться с его (нестандартными?) функциями работы с интервалами* нет там ничего особо нестандартного. Есть стандартная функция перевода `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, а потом хоть `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`, хоть просто вычитай. Скорее в постгрессе комбинация функции и оператора `EXTRACT(EPOCH` неочевидна - из разряда "только запомнить", хотя и можно использовать более очевидную `to_timestamp()`.

Comment: @Akina  Я имел в виду, что функции не из стандарта _SQL,_ в отличие от `EXTRACT`.  Сейчас перелистал _draft,_ и похоже, что там ни `EPOCH` в `EXTRACT`, ни `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.  Забавно.

Comment: Да не, нормально. Если поубирать все расширения, включая и неописанные  стандартом функции, из любого диалекта - станет ну очень грустно.

Comment: @Akina  Переписал предложение на более корректное.

Comment: я честно начинающий изер sql в принципе, возможно и задача была не правильно мной поставлена вот оригинал
в таблице нету event_id
и как здесь оно учитывает, что возможно 5 сессий человек ничего не покупал, а на 6 купил? ведь должно быть посчитано именно игровое время

Comment: @immense  Если нет `event_id`, то какой же там первичный ключ?  Второй вопрос не понял.  Мой вариант находит интервал между _первым_ стартом и _первой_ покупкой.  Если это не то, что вам нужно, уточните оригинальный вопрос.

Comment: Добавил скрин, в следующий раз лучше сразу добавлю, а то только время чужое трачу

Comment: @immense  Раз: за исключением вопросов о вёрстке, скриншоты зло: не индексируются поисковиками, текст из них не скопируешь, а в вашем случае ещё и разрешение мелкое.  Два: из вашего скриншота так и не ясно, что является в таблице первичным ключом.  Три: сделал вторую фантазию на тему, смотрите ответ.  Дальше сами.

Comment: Всё так, огромное спасибо за время, это шикус)

Comment: @immense  Не за что.  Не забывайте голосовать за ответы и отмечать их как верные.